# How do I test whether an nltk resource is already installed on the machine running my code?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I just started my first NLTK project and am confused about the proper setup. I need several resources like the Punkt Tokenizer and the maxent pos tagger. I myself downloaded them using the GUI `nltk.download()`. For my collaborators I of course want that this things get downloaded automatically. I haven't found any idiomatic code for that in the docu.

Am I supposed to just put `nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')` and their like into the code? Is this going to download the resources every time the script is run? Am I to provide feedback to the  user (i.e. my co-developers) of what is being downloaded and why this is taking so long? There MUST be gear out there that does the job, right? :)

//Edit To explify my question: 
**How do I test whether an nltk resource (like the Punkt Tokenizer) is already installed on the machine running my code, and install it if it is not?**

Comment: I'm having trouble determining what you're asking. A concise, testable code example demonstrating your current approach would be very helpful.

Comment: Let me reframe the question: How do I test whether an nltk resource (like the Punkt Tokenizer) is already installed on the machine running my code, and install it if it is not?

Comment: Edit your question to match your comment. Putting the short question in the comments may let it get overlooked

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use the `nltk.data.find()` function, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt.zip')
ZipFilePathPointer(u'/home/alvas/nltk_data/tokenizers/punkt.zip', u'')
```

When the resource is not available you'll find the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk-3.0a3-py2.7.egg/nltk/data.py", line 615, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError: 
**********************************************************************
  Resource u'punkt.zip' not found.  Please use the NLTK Downloader
  to obtain the resource:  >>> nltk.download()
  Searched in:
    - '/home/alvas/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/share/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/lib/nltk_data'
    - '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

Most probably, you would like to do something like this to ensure that your collaborators have the package:

```
>>> try:
...     nltk.data.find('tokenizers/punkt')
... except LookupError:
...     nltk.download('punkt')
... 
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to /home/alvas/nltk_data...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
True
```

Comment: There is a trap to this approach, which is that you can't reliably use it to install the data in a non-interactive application. Python will import nltk _without_ the downloaded resource. If you discover this fact with a LookupError and then try to run `nltk.download` and then re-import the relevant nltk module, Python will believe nltk was already imported and not re-import anything. So even though you'll have downloaded the new data artifact, the imported version of NLTK will still be the one that was booted up without access to it.

Comment: For example, you often need `from nltk import wordnet` but this submodule of nltk only exists if wordnet was downloaded prior to when nltk was imported. If you `try` .. `except` this import and check for `LookupError` and then dynamically run `nltk.download('wordnet')`, it will indeed install the data for wordnet, but re-running `from nltk import wordnet` will still fail (the `nltk` module being referenced will still be the one that booted up with no `wordnet` submodule in it).

Comment: @ely what's the remedy then?

Comment: PEP8 recommends to set all imports at the top of the file. In this case, anyway, it seems we can avoid the trap only running first "import nltk", then the try-except clause, and finally the specific import like "from nltk import ...".
This seems a bit of workaround anyway.

Comment: Or maybe "from nltk import data, download" first, and after the try-except surround "import nltk"?

Comment: @Fab Can you share a code with the workaround? I don't seem to understand it very clearly.

Comment: @SomnathRakshit, I'm posting an example below

Answer (score 4):

After Somnath comment, I am posting an example of the try-except workaround. Here we search for the comtrans module that is not in the nltk data by default.

```
from nltk.corpus import comtrans
from nltk import download

try:
    words = comtrans.words('alignment-en-fr.txt')
except LookupError:
    print('resource not found. Downloading now...')
    download('comtrans')
    words = comtrans.words('alignment-en-fr.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

Thought I'd give my 2 cents on this even if a bit late to the party.

nltk has two functions: download and downloader.

download() already contains logic that checks if the package is downloaded & up to date:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from nltk import download as nltk_download
from typing import List, Any
from nltk.downloader import Downloader
import logging

def download_nltk_data(
        list_of_resources: List[str],
        download_dir: Path,
) -> None:
    for resource in list_of_resources:
        nltk_download(
            info_or_id=resource,
            download_dir=download_dir,
            quiet=True, # Change this if you wanna suppress the message
        )

download_nltk_data(
    list_of_resources=[
        'stopwords',
        'punkt',
    ],
    download_dir=Path('./data/nltk/'),
)
```

Output:

```
[nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to data\nltk...
[nltk_data]   Package stopwords is already up-to-date!
[nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to data\nltk...
[nltk_data]   Package punkt is already up-to-date!
```

All you need to do is change quiet=True if you want to suppress this.

If for some reason you want finer control over the packages you can use the Downloader class and extend functionality:

```py
def check_package_exists(
    package_id: Any,
    download_dir: Path,
) -> bool:
    downloader = Downloader(download_dir=str(download_dir))
    return downloader.is_installed(package_id)

def download_nltk_data(
    list_of_resources: List[str],
    download_dir: Path,
) -> None:
    download_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    downloader = Downloader(download_dir=str(download_dir))
    for resource in list_of_resources:
        if not check_package_exists(resource, download_dir):
            logging.debug(f'Downloading {resource} to {download_dir}')
            downloader.download(info_or_id=resource, quiet=True)
        else:
            logging.debug(f'{resource} already exists in {download_dir}')


download_nltk_data(
    list_of_resources=[
        'stopwords',
        'punkt',
    ],
    download_dir=Path('./data/nltk/'),
)
```

Output:

```
stopwords already exists in data\nltk
punkt already exists in data\nltk
```

Or something like that